# Memory-mapped file - The most effective mapping size when using mmap()

Tags: c, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I'm working on 'database' program where I store objects in one file. 
I want to read objects using `mmap()` function.


The storage is document-oriented database, where objects are formed into a tree.
The object struct (it has a size of 64 bytes) looks like this:

```
struct Entity {
    section_off key_ptr;
    size_t key_size;
    section_off val_ptr;
    size_t val_size;
    enum value_type val_type;
    file_off ancestor_ptr;
    file_off child_ptr;
    file_off sibling_ptr; // ptr to next child of the same ancestor
};
```

I store these objects in the sections into which the file is divided. Each section has a size of 8 Kbytes and begins with `section_header` struct:

```
struct section_header {
    size_t free_space;
    section_off first_free_cell;
    section_off last_free_cell; 
    file_off section_addr;
};
```

So the question is: 
What size part of the file do I need to map in order to go through all objects in my file? Should it be the size of a single section, multiple sections or the entire file? The file size can be unlimited.

I need to go through not only all the objects in the file, but also get some exact objects by it's address. So I should already have a function, that would map a certain object from a file or the entire section with this object. Therefore, I don't know if I need to implement a function, that would map multiple sections to go through the entire file faster.

Comment: You should map the entire file. Then you can use the offsets as indexes into this mapping without any complicated rebasing.

Comment: @Barmar This comment sounds like an answer. 

Comment: @BlackJack Yeah, but then I'd have to write the code to show how to do it, and that's more work than I'm willing to put in. If they'd posted existing code that I could modify, I'd answer.